# Как согласовать сказуемое?

Tags: согласование, сказуемые, единственное-множественное-число

*Треть водителей признались, что садились за руль пьяными.*

Верно ли согласование во множественном числе со словом «треть»?
В единственном как-то странно было бы: *призналась, что садилась*...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Треть водителей признал**ись**, что садил**ись** за руль пьяными.*

В таком предложении формальное грамматическое согласование (*треть водителей признал**ась**, что садил**ась** пьян**ой***) "не звучит".

> • **согласование по смыслу:** сказуемое принимает форму множественного числа, поскольку подлежащее обозначает множество предметов или явлений: *большинство граждан проголосовали за нового президента, ряд пользователей отказались от платной услуги.*
> <...>
> **Согласование по смыслу** предпочтительно:
> <...>
> 3) если нужно подчеркнуть раздельность действий каждого действующего лица, называемого подлежащим, а также подчеркнуть активность действующих лиц: *Ряд сотрудников нашей организации выступили с инициативой;* ср.: *В прошлом году было построено множество дорог.*

Прилагательное "пьяными" в конце предложения также способствует использованию множественного числа.

> *Большинство домов в этой деревне были деревянными.*

Источник: [**Грамота.ру**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo).